# "hg push" reports "added 1 changesets with 0 changes to 0 files." Huh?

Tags: mercurial, merge, push, bitbucket

Using Mercurial, I've just done a merge/commit/push sequence, and the push reported:

`remote: added 1 changesets with 0 changes to 0 files`

... which had me freaking out for a few seconds.

The full sequence of commands and outputs was:

```
% hg merge -r that_other_branch
63 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved
(branch merge, don't forget to commit)
% hg status
... <63 files marked 'M', one marked 'R'> ...
% hg commit
% hg push
pushing to ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/mycompany/mycompany-coolwebsite
searching for changes
remote: adding changesets
remote: adding manifests
remote: adding file changes
remote: added 1 changesets with 0 changes to 0 files
%
```

When I look at the remote repository (on Bitbucket), I see that it does list all 64 files, and the diffs look right. So I'm satisfied that the merge and push did what I wanted, but that last message from `hg push` has me mystified.

Is this a bug in Mercurial? (`hg --version` reports "2.6+20130507", and I'm on OS X 10.8.5)

Or is the message correct, and I'm just too dense to understand what it's trying to communicate?

(If it makes a difference, the files in the head revision of the target branch were identical to the files in the ancestor revision common to that head and 'that_other_branch' -- which accounts for why there were all 'updates' and no 'merges' resulting from the `hg merge`.)

Comment: did you do a transplant from some other branch ? This happens to me when i do a transplant. Not sure why ??

Comment: @YugandharPathi This was over 5 years (and many projects) ago, so my memory may be faulty -- but I don't think I *ever* did a transplant when I was using Mercurial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything's probably fine.  Since that 1 new changeset is a merge it's probably being excluded from those totals since every change it contains is already in one head or another that's already on the remote repo.

Other changesets that could yield a similar message are those that only alter the permissions of files, but that's clearly not the case here.

Comment: Interesting. I thought it might be something like that, but couldn't articulate it clearly enough in my own mind to convince myself. Incidentally, a commit option that also results in a similar message is `--close-branch`.

Comment: Good one @Hephaestus I'd not thought about a branch close but that makes sense too.

Comment: I just pushed another merge commit that had 3 files with conflicts I'd resolved (out of 20-some-odd files total), and Mercurial reported `added 1 changesets with 3 changes to 3 files (-1 heads)`, which is in line with your analysis. So thanks for helping me flesh out my mental model of what's going on inside Mercurial.